# Passing $scope to object stored function inside ng-click

Tags: angularjs

Ok, I was not sure how to describe this question, but let´s give it a a try.

I have an angular controller that is supposed to work with different datasources, depending on given values.

```
var RowCtrl = function($scope, RowService, $http, $timeout, $compile){
    $scope.rows = RowService.getRows();
    $scope.columns = RowService.getColumns();
    $scope.search = function()
    ...
    $scope.insert = function()
    ...
    etc...
```

The RowService injected has to be provided with rows and columns values

There is also a MailController that shows a form that allows to send an email.

In different pages, I have a code that looks more or less like this one:

```
app.controller('EmployeesController', function($scope, $controller) {
        angular.extend(this, $controller('RowCtrl', {$scope: $scope}));
        angular.extend(this, $controller('MailCtrl', {$scope: $scope}));
    });
    app.value("rows", <?php echo json_encode($empleados); ?>);
    app.value("columns", [
        {name:"id", view:false, pk:true},
        {name:"nombre", view:false, mandatory:true},
        {name:"apellidos", view:false, mandatory:true},
        {name:"empleado", label:"Empleado", main:true, value:function(){ return this.nombre+" "+this.apellidos; }, create:false, edit:false},
        {name:"email", label:"Email", click:function(row){ mailForm({toName:row.nombre+" "+row.apellidos, to:row.email }); }},
        {name:"telefono", label:"Teléfono"}
    ]);
```

If you look at the "email" column, I added a click property, so I can declare custom events on different columns.

And this is the template where it is used:

```
<div class = 'col' ng-repeat = 'column in columns  | filter: {view:"!false", main:"!true"}'>
    <a ng-if = 'column.click' ng-click = 'column.click(row)'>{{getCellValue(row, column)}}</a>
    <p ng-if = '!column.click'>{{getCellValue(row, column)}}</p>
</div>
```

So, it does work as long is I have a mailForm function defined, but what I would prefer is to have the MailCtrl take care of this operation, so, the question is, is there any way I can do something like this (refering to the current scope when the function is called):

```
...
{name:"email", label:"Email", click:function(row){ $scopeWhereTheFunctionWasCalled.mail()  }}
...
```

Thanks in advance, and don´t be cruel, 1st angular project :)

Comment: I'm not understanding what you are trying to do.  Can you fork this code pen and make an example of the issue?  http://codepen.io/mkl/pen/GqmKKe?editors=1010

Comment: Sure: http://codepen.io/sergio0983/pen/OXmvBj?editors=1010 If you look at click attribute on email column, it defines a click function for the column "email" on every row. What i want is to call the one that i defined in the scope, but don´t know how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call the function that is defined in `$scope` you will need to have the function defined in the columns[] like this:

```
$scope.columns = [{
 name: "id",
 view: false,
 pk: true,
}, {
 name: "nombre",
 view: false,
 mandatory: true
}, {
 name: "apellidos",
 view: false,
 mandatory: true
}, {
 name: "empleado",
 label: "Full Name",
 main: true,
 value: function() {
  return this.nombre + " " + this.apellidos;
 },
 create: false,
 edit: false
}, {
 name: "email",
 label: "Email",
 click: function(row) {
  $scope.mailForm({
    toName: row.nombre + " " + row.apellidos,
    to: row.email
  });
 }
}, {
 name: "telefono",
 label: "Telephone"
}];
```

here is the working example on [codepen](http://codepen.io/mkl/pen/GqmKKe)

Comment: Ok, it´s weird, but it works as long as the columns are not injected from the outside world. I need to pass rows and columns to a service, that´s why I used app.value instead of declaring it in the scope. Even though this will work for now, as I can just ignore the columns in the factory (I assume they are not going to change), I´d like to know if there is a better way to handle this. Doing app.value to inject rows so i can declare the factory with preloaded rows doesn´t seem clean to me.

Comment: if you can create a simple codepen showing how you want it to work I can take a look at that example and I might be able to help determine the best pattern.

Comment: Thank you, but I just changed the approach and got what I wanted, too many hours of work and i couldn´t see that it was as simple as having a setRows(datasource_name) function in the factory, then I can use app.value("datasource", all_datasources), and swap datasources in different controllers. A complete codepen would include some more directives, and would be far too long. The goal was to have a generic controller able to handle create, update, and delete any records, and directives with a box that would show paginated records, and that´s why I needed to specify different datasources